# SVG path isn't displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I'm using FusionChartXT and my Line chart doesn't display the div lines in IE.

Now I looked at the svg code
That's the code for one divline in internet-explorer:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill: none; stroke: #bbbbbb; stroke-opacity: 0.7;" fill="none" stroke="#bbbbbb" stroke-dasharray="-6" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" d="M 32 438.5 L 438 438.5" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
```

And this is the code in Chrome, where the line is displayed:

```
<path d="M33,167.5L438,167.5" stroke="#bbbbbb" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="-6" fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges" style="stroke: rgb(187, 187, 187); stroke-opacity: 0.7; fill: none; shape-rendering: crispEdges;"></path>
```

So because I'm not really good with svg graphics, I don't see why it isn't working in IE.

**Update**
There is a bug in IE that causes paths with markers to render improperly. But I don't really know if I have markers in my code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) a negative value for `stroke-dasharray` is considered an error. In this case IE seems to be adhering closer to the spec than other browsers which might be more fault-tolerant. Try to correct your path to contain correct values (i.e. positive values) for `stroke-dasharray`.

Comment: Well, it is showing a line now, but I have no idea where i have to change anything in the FusionChart code

Comment: If you need help with your code, we need to see at least the relevant parts of it which cause the problem.

Comment: Have a look at the section *Divisional Lines & Grids* in the documentation of the [chart attributes](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=line). There are some attributes like `divLineDashed`, `divLineDashLen` and `divLineDashGap` which, judging by their names, might affect `stroke-dasharray`.

Comment: It is working if I set the "divLineIsDashed" to 1. But I don't want to have a dashed line.